# Aviary HTM5L sample not working in iOS Safari (photo appears to keep loading)

Tags: aviary

I took the sample HTML5 and tried in iOS Safari.

The sample photo appears but keeps loading continuously and no Aviary editing actions can be performed.

Does anybody have a solution?

Here's the sample code directly from the Aviary site at http://www.aviary.com/web-documentation

```
<!-- Load Feather code -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js"></script>

<!-- Instantiate Feather -->

<script type="text/javascript">

        var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({

            apiKey: '12345678',

            apiVersion: 2,

            tools: 'all',

            appendTo: 'injection_site',

            onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {

                var img = document.getElementById(imageID);

                img.src = newURL;

            }

        });



        function launchEditor(id, src) {

            featherEditor.launch({

                image: id,

                url: src

            });

            return false;

        }

</script>



    <div id="injection_site"></div>



    <img id="image1" src="http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg"/>



    <!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL ot the image -->

    <p><input type="image" src="http://advanced.aviary.com/images/feather/edit-photo.png" value="Edit photo" onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" /></p>
```

Comment: You might want to remove your API key from your code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Aviary at api@aviary.com and they mentioned that there was a bug that they fixed today. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this code on live server, local does't seem to work here. Aviary web documentation says that "Set a location on your server for Aviary to send a server-to-server HTTP POST".

Comment: The OP answered that the problem was bug in Aviary itself and now the bug is fixed. Is there a reason to suggest new solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case...
You must add the complete 'src' in the photo.
Instead us using "src='/upload/miPhoto.png'" you must use "src='http://localhost:8080/project/upload/miPhoto.png'"
Hope this helps!